# Redirecting Old blog address to a new blog address permanently in blogger

Tags: blogger

I'm having a blogger blog and it's custom domain expires in a week. So, I planned to create a new blog and redirect the custom domain to the new blog domain. Consider, my old domain is `old-blog.blogspot.com` and I wish to redirect all the links to the old blog to my new address `new-blog.blogspot.com`. So, was there any ways doing it?

As I googled, I read about doing that with blogger conditional statements and that should be done for every post. But, in my blog I've more than 200 posts. Any ways?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try to use javascript.

Put the following code inside `<head>` tag in your template.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var d='<data:blog.url/>';
  d=d.replace(/.*\/\/[^\/]*/, '');
  location.href = 'http://new-blog.blogspot.com'+d;
</script>
```

This will redirect user to the new domain and to the same post URL as in old domain.

Comment: This solutions is not working in blogger dynamic views. Should it be something else for that?

Comment: Can anyone explain regex used?? I'm wanting change it a little bit.

Comment: I'm a wee bit late - but the regex finds everything before the first slash in the site path/page and removes it

Comment: for example, it would replace `https://google.com/foobar/test.html` with `foobar/test.html`. Then it does `http://new-blog.blogspot.com` + `foobar/test.html`

Answer (score 3):

I did a lot of searching for how to migrate my Blogger account so that:

1. Each blog post at the old URL gets redirected to the same blog post on the new URL (e.g. `http://old-url.blogspot.com/bar` gets redirected to `http://new-url.com/bar`).
2. You do the redirect in a way that doesn't lose SEO rank. This means that JavaScript solutions (e.g. the accepted answer in this post) won't work, as you need a server-side generated `<link rel="canonical" href="http://new-url.com/bar"/>` tag in the `<head>`.

I found no satisfying answers, so to help others in the future, I thought I'd add the hack I came up with here. The reason you need a hack is that blogger templates use some [arcane XML syntax](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/46995?hl=en) that allows basic variable lookups, loops, and if-statements, but as far as I can tell, there is no way to do string manipulation to accomplish the URL transformation in requirement #1 above. To work around this, you can generate a hard-coded list of if-statements that check every possible URL you care about and redirect it to the proper place. Something along the lines of:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.canonicalUrl == "http://old-url.blogspot.com/url1"'>
  <link rel="canonical" href="http://new-url.com/url1"/>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://new-url.com/url1"/>
<b:elseif cond='data:blog.canonicalUrl == "http://old-url.blogspot.com/url2"'/>
  <link rel="canonical" href="http://new-url.com/url2"/>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://new-url.com/url2"/>
<b:elseif cond='data:blog.canonicalUrl == "http://old-url.blogspot.com/url3"'/>
  <link rel="canonical" href="http://new-url.com/url3"/>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://new-url.com/url3"/>
<!-- And so on, one if-statement per blog post -->
```

If you can do basic scripting, you don't have to generate these if-statements (and there may be hundreds) by hand. Instead, you can [export your Blogger posts](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/97416?hl=en) to an XML file and write a simple script to read in each URL in that file and generate the if-statement above. I wrote a blog post about migrating from [Blogger to GitHub Pages](http://www.ybrikman.com/writing/2015/04/20/migrating-from-blogger-to-github-pages/) where I explain all the gory details and the Ruby script I used to generate the if-statements is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/brikis98/yevgeniy-brikman-homepage/blob/gh-pages/_scripts/redirect_urls.rb). Note that this is a very hacky script customized for my blog, and it actually runs against the Jekyll conversion of the blogger XML export, but you can use it as a base to create your own script and avoid lots of weird blogger template error messages.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up taking the same path that you did, I just  wrote my own blogger template generator as well as the script that simplifies html files and creates md files in F#: [gist](https://gist.github.com/hoonzis/de264faa619c9390eb97)

Comment: Super helpful, thanks.  Something else I had to do was set `timezone: "America/Chicago"` in my `_config.yml`, otherwise GH Pages would put posts into folders based on UTC, which didn't always match the dates generated by the script.  I could also have run the script with `TZ=""` to match GH Pages, different people will have different opinions about which is more correct.

Answer (score 1):

For viewers who might have Javascript turned off (which is rare these days, but not unheard of), you can put

```
<meta content='0;url=http://your-new-url.tld' http-equiv='refresh'/>
```

instead.

Or do both :)

Answer (score 0):

you must import your blog

click setting and click other and then click impor blog

Next save your result download ( XML file ) and then click your new blog, then click setting then click other then click ekspor blog then upload your result download ( XML file ) finish

Comment: That explains only for changing posts from one blog to another but, I asked about redirection.

Comment: <script type='text/javascript'>
window.location.replace("your URL")
</script>